# chat application using web socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

**I have created a chat application using web socket.I also deploy it on the heroku but client.js file is not working properly.**
`Maybe the problem with the process.env.PORT but not sure.`
client.js:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

Error:client.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at client.js:2
```

**This is index.js file**

```
const express=require('express');
var app=express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const socketIO=require('socket.io');

var path=require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/index.html');
})

var server=app.listen(PORT,()=>{

    console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
})
```

**Index.html**

```
<script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script defer src="./js/client.js"></script>
```

Please help me.

Comment: i am using socket.io instead of ws module

Comment: "http://localhost:3000" points to your local machine, from where you visiting the website. This must be your heroku instance/public server. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Replace `io("http://localhost:3000")` with just `io()`

Comment: I tried that but that is not working may be the issue with index.html. what to do with this <script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>` or install it if you're using a bundler as described in [the docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/index.html)